# Trying to pass a struct with 3 variables in a thread function which generates a sequence of random integers, to be placed in a circular buffer

Tags: c, function, struct, segmentation-fault, pthreads

This function is executed by a thread. I believe the error occurs when I try to access rand_count which, is a variable of the struct called args. Note that the problem is located in the for loop of the producer.

```
void* Producers(void* fargs) {
    printf("I am Producer and I am not locked\n");
    args* f_args=(args*) fargs;
    rc = pthread_mutex_lock(&Mutex);
    printf("I am Producer and I am locked\n");
    if (rc != 0) {  
        printf("ERROR: return code from pthread_mutex_lock() is %d\n", rc);
        pthread_exit(&rc);
    }
    printf(" The ruler of all mutexes has passed from here and shall start creating random numbers\n");
    for(int i=0; i < *f_args->rand_count; ++i) {
        printf ( "Creating random number\n");
        my_random =rand_r(f_args->seed)%255;

        if(i==cb->capacity) {
            printf(" Your producer king will now sleep\n");
            rc = pthread_cond_signal(&Condition);
            if (rc != 0) {  
                printf("ERROR: return code from pthread_cond_signal() is %d\n", rc);
                pthread_exit(&rc);
            }

            rc = pthread_cond_wait(&Condition, &Mutex);
            if (rc != 0) {  
                printf("ERROR: return code from pthread_cond_wait() is %d\n", rc);
                pthread_exit(&rc);
            }

        }
        cb_push_back(cb, &my_random);
        if(i==0) {
            fp=fopen("prod_in.txt", "w");
        } else {
            fp=fopen("prod_in.txt", "a");
        }
        fprintf(fp, "Producer %d: %d\n", f_args->ID, my_random);
    }

    rc = pthread_cond_signal(&Condition);
    if (rc != 0) {  
        printf("ERROR: return code from pthread_cond_signal() is %d\n", rc);
        pthread_exit(&rc);
    }

    rc = pthread_mutex_unlock(&Mutex);
    if (rc != 0) {  
        printf("ERROR: return code from pthread_mutex_unlock() is %d\n", rc);
        pthread_exit(&rc);
    }
}
```

This is the struct

```
typedef struct args{
    int ID;             //Unique ID from 1 to n 
    int* seed;          //The seed used for rand_r
    int* rand_count;    //The number of random generated numbers
}args;
```

Comment: Can you show how the thread is set up & started?  The problem might be there.

Comment: Sure thing 

rc = pthread_create(&p1, NULL, Producers, (void*)t_args);

Comment: Your question refers to "the error" and "the problem" but does not actually describe the symptoms of "the problem" or describe "the error".

Comment: Yes my bad. I put it in the tag so I thought it would be enough. The error is segmentation fault (core dumped).

Comment: And what is `cb` and `cb_push_back`?

Comment: How does `t_args` get allocated & filled?

Comment: The code in main function was too big to upload. Can I upload the main function separately. As for your question. I allocate the memory with (args*)malloc(sizeof(struct args)). The cb and cb_push_back are functions provided to me for the assignment. cb is a pointer to the struck circular buffer. As I said above the code was too big to upload altogether.

Comment: How do the fields of the struct get filled?

Comment: This is what I did
t_args->seed=(int*)atoi(argv[5]);
t_args->rand_count=(int*)atoi(argv[4]);
t_args->ID=1;

Comment: "This is what I did t_args->seed=(int*)atoi(argv[5]); t_args->rand_count=(int*)atoi(argv[4]); t_args->ID=1;". Oh, that explains it. You can't just convert the result of `atoi` to a pointer and and expect it to work. You need to point `t_args->seed` and `t_args->rand_count` to actual `int` variables.

Comment: I'll try it out tomorrow. Thanks!

Comment: Turns out this was not the problem after all. I still get segmentation fault (core dumped) at that same point of the code and the for loop does not start.